# VC# Realtime event log?

Tags: .net, wpf, events, logging, real-time

I'm writing an WPF application in Virtual Studio 2012 which uses both voice commands and input over LAN from an iOS app, but I want to have a way to monitor what the vocal recognition *thinks* it receives and what the app supplies as well.

I've seen a few applications have these realtime loggers as a textbox window that prints certain events when they occur; most notably, the Minecraft server application. This screenshot points out the log I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu0dU.jpg

I know Minecraft is programmed in Java in stead of C#, but is there a way to get something like this thing into my application?

Comment: a log is really just code saying "append the following text to my existing textbox". no other magic behind it, you simply choose significant parts of your program and write your text to be logged and/or displayed.

Comment: I've tried that and I can't get it to work. Could you give me an example code?

Comment: `Virtual Studio 2012` - EPIC. It's called Visual Studio. Not Virtual Studio, and it's the only serious IDE in the planet. Have respect.

Comment: @HighCore Did you come here to correct me or help me?

Comment: @user2454178 No, I came here to close-vote your non-question. Until you have a concrete specific question about a particular piece of code or functionality.

Comment: if you've tried that and did not get it to work, you are in luck. simply show us what you tried and where you think it fails and we can help you out. without code, we cannot help.